# Difference between brightness and lightness in Image Manipulation

Tags: android, image-manipulation, android-image

I have an application to adjust the lightness/brightness of the image and the saturation and i found this link [here](http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html) which uses android colormatrix to adjust the brightness. Here's the function to adjust brightness in colormatrix.

```
public static void adjustBrightness(ColorMatrix cm, float value) {
value = cleanValue(value,50);
if (value == 0) {
    return;
}

float[] mat = new float[]
{ 
    1,0,0,0,value,
    0,1,0,0,value,
    0,0,1,0,value,
    0,0,0,1,0
};
cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));
```

}

But i don't know if there's a difference with lightness in brightness. Because in GIMP software there is lightness and brightness. See the screenshot below. If there's another method to adjust lightness/brigthness saturation at the same time I would be happy to see it :).

[image] [image]

Comment: What you improperly call `Lightness` is the `Luminance` and it's a component in the **HSL** color space (as opposed to the **RGB** color space). http://www.larry-bolch.com/shade/hsl.htm

Comment: Wow @FrankN.Stein nice link. It really explains what Lightness is, I like the link because it provides the easy picture of what is Lightness is. :). Thanks man.

Comment: Archive link for the page linked above, which has since gone offline: https://web.archive.org/web/20181010163341/http://www.larry-bolch.com:80/shade/hsl.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brightness is visual perception related with reflecting or radiating of lights of different frequencies. On the otherhand lightness is TONE which moves from Darkest color to lightest color of same color Gamma is nothing but an attribute to handle luminescence Means how bright should be the image be (it's more a mathematical calculation rather definition.

In non technical words we can say

Lightness seems to more affect the saturation of the photograph, whereas brightness seems to affect how vivid the colors look.

If you want to go in deep for the proof of concepts, please follow this
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698910004578

Comment: Hi @Awadesh, thanks man. I think i got it but i would like to visit the link you provided :). You are quick.